# Firebird delete+insert vs update+insert

Tags: sql, database, firebird, rdbms

I just want to know which is faster in firebird. If it's delete then insert all the data or the UPDATE OR INSERT query in the firebird database, my data for this is almost a hundred thousand records.

Comment: The answer is "it depends." The performance of either method depends on your data, queries, indexes and schema. The only way to know for sure is to try it both ways and compare.

Comment: If the rows in question are referenced from other tables you might not even be able to do the `delete`

Comment: The question should be less about what's faster and more about what gives you data integrity.  I'd assume an upsert is what you're looking for, and is likely more performant anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for `update or insert`.  Delete is not that fast on firebird.  Also, bulk deletes will leave that space unused in the file.  If you do this often, the file will stay larger than it needs to be.  Until you backup and restore.